# How to call an application which is located on my desktop through shinyApp?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to call an application which is installed on my system under c:// drive.
I want to call 'tableau.exe' application by clicking on action button in a shinyApp.

My code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('run','Run executable!')
)

server<- function(input,output)
{
  observeEvent(input$run,
               {
                 system("cmd.exe", input = "tableau.bat")
               })
}
```

shinyApp(ui,server)

Comment: Hey there. Can you share how your current app looks like and what you've tried so far?As a general pointer towards your question, i'd suggest to take a look at `system` where you can invoke various OS commands.

Comment: For Windows I'd rather look at `shell` (user-friendly wrapper for `system`)

Comment: I got Florian's code for calling notepad. Code added in code section.

Answer (score 0):

In server code: the line "system("cmd.exe", input = "tableau.bat")" would call the tableau.exe file. For any '.exe' file calling through shinyApp require a '.bat' file save in the work space.